# Get information on an artifact, without version number

Tags: api, rest, nexus

I am trying to use the nexus API, in order to retrieve a maven artifact.

The problem is that I want in a first step to propose the user to chose the version number. To do so, I thought I could use the REST API, but regarding the [documentation](https://repository.sonatype.org/nexus-restlet1x-plugin/default/docs/index.html), it seems that it is not possible.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the alternative REST API provided by the [Nexus Indexer Lucene Plugin](https://repository.sonatype.org/nexus-indexer-lucene-plugin/default/docs/path__lucene_search.html)

The following example retrieves details of the available log4j artifacts:

- https://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/lucene/search?g=log4j&a=log4j